# Why did Frank jr and Alice need Phoebe to carry their children?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

If their baby(ies) were from Alice's ova and Frank's sperm, why did they have to grow in Phoebe's womb (her oven, totally their bun, as Phoebe describes it)? I know out of universe it was to explain Lisa Kudrow's eventual baby-bump- was there an in-universe reason?

Answer (score 12):

In universe -

**Alice(44) was Frank's(18)** home economics teacher in high school. They both start dating in season 3. They get engaged and Alice is introduced to the gang in the episode "The one with the Hypnosis Tape". They decide they want to get married and have babies.

In "the one with Phoebe's uterus", they get married and they ask a favour of Phoebe to carry their embryo/child. **Since at an age of 44 the rates of conceiving babies comparatively becomes difficult, they ask Phoebe to carry their baby for them.** Phoebe accepts to be their surrogate.

Coming to the show the writers probably thought that would be good way to utilise Lisa Kudrow's real pregnancy

Comment: There are also medical reasons to choose surrogacy (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Surrogacy) in addition to age.

Comment: yes i do agree, but in the show, it was always implied that she was aged for frank and that she probably couldn't concieve due to the age factor.

Comment: Woah... I didn't know Lisa was actually preganant.

Comment: It's not uncommon to work a real pregnancy into the plot for a female actress's character.  Worth noting, perhaps, that Lisa Kudrow was only pregnant with *one* baby, though ;)

Comment: And, you know, Friends being a light comedy, they probably didn't really need more than a flimsy premise, rather than solid, reliable scientific backing. Realism was only a passing concern (and rightfully so) - Think any of them would be able to afford a NYC apartment of that size on their incomes for the jobs they held?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet light comedy is a new thing I get to know. what other types of comedy are there? I know some racist type things(forgot the name). is there heavy/dark comedy?

Comment: @Vishwa - There is definitely dark comedy (Ash vs the Evil Dead), sarcastic comedy (Veep), deadpan comedy (The Office), slapstick comedy (the Three Stooges) - to name a few.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Sarcastic comedy is the most common I think, long before Chandler Bing. thank you for the list. gonna look into those a lil bit more